# jQuery animation doesn't work the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

Why in [THIS CODE](http://codepen.io/balapa/pen/embYYB) if you press the "I" button on the bottom right the first time works, but the second it shows just the pink background?

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';

  var $mainButton = $(".main-button"),
      $closeButton = $(".close-button"),
      $buttonWrapper = $(".button-wrapper"),
      $ripple = $(".ripple"),
      $layer = $(".layered-content");

  $mainButton.on("click", function(){
    $ripple.addClass("rippling");
    $buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked").delay(1500).queue(function(){
      $layer.addClass("active");
    });
  });

  $closeButton.on("click", function(){
    $buttonWrapper.removeClass("clicked");
    $ripple.removeClass("rippling");
    $layer.removeClass("active");
  });

})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300);

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("http://species-in-pieces.com/img/bg/grad-bg.png") no-repeat center center/cover #F9D8AD;
  height: 100%;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fa-info {
  color: white;
}

#container {
  width: 330px;
  height: 508px;
  max-width: 330px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

h2 {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: #3E4FB2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.detail {
  color: #777;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.img-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(62, 79, 178, .25);
  width: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.button-wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
}

.main-button {
  background: #ff2670;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -9;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ff2670;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(.5);
  transform: scale(.5);
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
  transition: .3s all ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.rippling {
  -webkit-animation: .3s rippling 1;
  animation: .3s rippling 1;
  -moz-animation: .3s rippling 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rippling {

  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }

}

@-moz-keyframes rippling {

  25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }

}

@keyframes rippling {

  25% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }

}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ff2670;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -99;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button-wrapper.clicked {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-96px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-96px);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-96px);
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease .6s;
  transition: .3s all ease .6s;
}

.button-wrapper.clicked .main-button {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease .3s;
  transition: .3s all ease .3s;
}

.button-wrapper.clicked .layer {
  -webkit-transform: scale(100);
  -ms-transform: scale(100);
  transform: scale(100);
  -webkit-transition: 2.25s all ease .9s;
  transition: 2.25s all ease .9s;
}

.layered-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.layered-content.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close-button {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #ff2670;
}

.layered-content.active .close-button {
  -webkit-animation: .5s bounceIn;
  animation: .5s bounceIn;
}

.layered-content .content img {
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: 80px;
  shape-outside: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.content p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.content p a {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2.5px 5px;
  color: #ff2670;;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5px;
}

.content img,
.content p {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -7.5px;
}

.layered-content.active .content img {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease .5s;
  transition: .5s all ease .5s;
}

.layered-content.active .content p {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease 1s;
  transition: .5s all ease 1s;
}

.copyright {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
.copyright span {
  line-height: 36px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.copyright span a {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ea4c89;
}
.copyright .balapa {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: url("//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/111167/profile/profile-80_3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="container">
  <h2>Material Overlay Animation</h2>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/2733/screenshots/741958/dribbble-foxes.jpg" alt="Just Background">
  </div>
  <p class="detail">Click the Button to see the "Material Animation". Works great on modern browser.</p>

  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <button class="main-button fa fa-info">
      <div class="ripple"></div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="layered-content">
    <button class="close-button fa fa-times"></button>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/332135/avatars/normal/52d614ee44e3e21d2b73894c465773d7.png" alt="Balapa">
      <p>Crafted by balapa.</p>
      <p>See also my <a href="http://codepen.io/balapa/details/gbQbXR/">other pen</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<div class="copyright"><span>Material Overlay Animation by</span><a href="http://dribbble.com/balapa" class="balapa"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear the queue using `clearQueue()` function.

Change your code to this

```
...
    $buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked").clearQueue().delay(1500).queue(function(){
            $layer.addClass("active");
        });
    });
...
```

Or you can even do it like this which is a way suggested in jQuery documentation.

```
$buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked").delay(1500).queue(function(){
            $layer.addClass("active");
            jQuery.dequeue( this );
        });
    });
```

**Important** part directly from jQuery documentation,

> Note that when adding a function with jQuery.queue(), we should ensure
>   that jQuery.dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function
>   in line executes.

Comment: it will be great if you put the explaination too

Comment: @panagulis72 Mark the answer as correct if it was correct please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked").delay(1500).queue(function(){
   $layer.addClass("active");
});
```

Use this:

```
$buttonWrapper.addClass("clicked");
setTimeout(function(){$layer.addClass("active")},1500);
```

And it will work.

Comment: What is the difference between setTimeout and delay, and why it works just with setTimeout?

Comment: In general, setTimeout() is used for executing a function (or calling one) after a certain delay and works only once. Unlike .queue() of jQuery, you don't have to clear it (unless you need to stop it before it gets executed of course). In this particular case, setTimeout() works like a combination of .delay() and .queue() without the need for clearing (+ I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty confident that setTimeout() will also be faster)